# Find a function by it signature in Windows DLL

Tags: c++, c, assembly, signature, disassembly

Have found a function address in a DLL. Have no source code for this DLL, not mine. This DLL is not really changed frequently, but when changed, it is a problem for me to find it by disassembling. Saw some notes in web about making it signature and then find it by this saved signature. **Can you, please, give some ideas or working example on how to implement this?**

Comment: I don't understand how you can work without header file or documentation.

Comment: Function I want to use is not exported from the DLL. It is internal DLL function.

Comment: Yes, that's a subtle message that you aren't expected to call that function.

Comment: Can't you just buy the software so that you don't have to crack it? :) Anyway, having experience with disassembling, you should know that the DLL contains nothing that would allow you to find the function other than by code analysis. You can get function boundaries from x64 DLLs, but that's about it.

Comment: **David Heffernan**, You have to have some knowledge in assembly/disassembly to know how it can work.

Comment: **avakar**, ofcourse we know disassembly doesnot contain funcction names, arguments, etc. But as you mentioned code analysis, how can I analyse the code to make signature of some piece of code? I'm not cracking the DLL, just provide some additional functionality.

Comment: @Didar_Uranov: Actually code can contain function names through symbols, although these are often stripped in production code.

Comment: By the way if you want to search for more resources online, this technique is more commonly known as AOB (array of byte) searching/scanning or less commonly pattern finding/matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by code signature scanning, which is something I have done in the past. The concept mainly works by relying on the fact that functions often do not change too much between updates, but simply relocate because they were pushed forward or back by other functions being expanded or shrunk.

Let's take the example of `MessageBoxA`, who's disassembly looks like this for me:

```
765DEA11 > 8BFF             MOV EDI,EDI
765DEA13   55               PUSH EBP
765DEA14   8BEC             MOV EBP,ESP
765DEA16   833D 749A5E76 00 CMP DWORD PTR DS:[765E9A74],0
765DEA1D   74 24            JE SHORT USER32.765DEA43
765DEA1F   64:A1 18000000   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[18]
765DEA25   6A 00            PUSH 0
765DEA27   FF70 24          PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+24]
765DEA2A   68 A49E5E76      PUSH USER32.765E9EA4
765DEA2F   FF15 34145876    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.Interlocke>; kernel32.InterlockedCompareExchange
765DEA35   85C0             TEST EAX,EAX
765DEA37   75 0A            JNZ SHORT USER32.765DEA43
765DEA39   C705 A09E5E76 01>MOV DWORD PTR DS:[765E9EA0],1
765DEA43   6A 00            PUSH 0
765DEA45   FF75 14          PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]
765DEA48   FF75 10          PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]
765DEA4B   FF75 0C          PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
765DEA4E   FF75 08          PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
765DEA51   E8 73FFFFFF      CALL USER32.MessageBoxExA
765DEA56   5D               POP EBP
765DEA57   C2 1000          RETN 10
```

The trick is to guess at some block of code which you think is likely to stay the same in an update, but more importantly is unique to this function. Typically, it is useless to scan for the epilogue/prologue. I would probably take the following block:

```
765DEA16   833D 749A5E76 00 CMP DWORD PTR DS:[765E9A74],0
765DEA1D   74 24            JE SHORT USER32.765DEA43
765DEA1F   64:A1 18000000   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[18]
765DEA25   6A 00            PUSH 0
765DEA27   FF70 24          PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+24]
765DEA2A   68 A49E5E76      PUSH USER32.765E9EA4
765DEA2F   FF15 34145876    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.Interlocke>;
```

You have to make a balance when choosing the length of the block. The longer the block, the more likely it is to uniquely identify a function, but also the more likely it is that some code will be inserted during the update which means it is split, etc. Note that the block I have chosen has multiple memory references. We can not rely on any data or function addresses since these may be relocated on the next update, so we fill those bytes with wildcards:

```
765DEA16   833D XXXXXXXX 00 CMP DWORD PTR DS:[XXXXXXXX],0
765DEA1D   74 XX            JE SHORT XXXXXXXX
765DEA1F   64:A1 18000000   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[18]
765DEA25   6A 00            PUSH 0
765DEA27   FF70 24          PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+24]
765DEA2A   68 XXXXXXXX      PUSH XXXXXXXX
765DEA2F   FF15 XXXXXXXX    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[XXXXXXXX]
```

This means our byte signature is now:

> 0x83 0x3D 0x? 0x? 0x? 0x? 0x74 0x? 0x64 0xA1 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6A
>   0x00 0xFF 0x70 0x24 0x68 0x? 0x? 0x? 0x? 0xFF 0x15 0x? 0x? 0x? 0x?

The `0x?` bytes indicate wildcards which are bytes we expect to change. The other ones are bytes we expect will not change in the update. To use the bytes to locate the function at runtime, you need to scan for these bytes (taking into account the wildcards). The process is approximately so:

- Enumerate all executable pages of the process (`VirtualQueryEx`)
- Scan for the byte signature we found (taking into account the wildcards - this is trivial to implement as a `for` loop which skips wildcard bytes)
- To obtain the true function address, fix up the address you get with the offset of the block from the original function (in this case, `0x765DEA16 - 0x765DEA11 => 0x5`)

Actually, rather than enumerating all executable pages, it is often enough to find what module the function lies within (`user32.dll`) in this case, and search within that module only.

Comment: I wonder how we can call that function from c. Assign it to a pointer and call that? Does that work?

Comment: @alFReDNSH If the function takes no arguments, yes you can do that because it's okay to ignore call convention differences. Otherwise, you have to be more careful to make sure you cast it appropriately.

Comment: If it takes an int as first argument and returns an int, is the following right?

int lolz = 1;
int (*foo)(int);
foo = <function address>;
lolz = foo(lolz);

Comment: You would need to check the call convention. Such as `stdcall`, `cdecl`, etc.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat A working method I made use of is this

**First Make Sure your pointer is in the form of uintptr_t**

`reinterpret_cast<void *>("address in uintptr_t");` 
The code next to this will cast it to a function ptr
`reinterpret_cast<int(*)(int)>("the void* ptr from previous step");` This code is the inportant part it casts the void* into the correct return type with the correct arguments (this is the function call signature `"return type"(*)("arguement types here seporated with commas")`