# How to know the address range when searching for a function by its signature?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to search for a function by its "signature".

However I can't figure out what address range I'm supposed to be searching?

I've had a look at VirtualQuery() and GetNativeSystemInfo() but I'm not if I'm on the right path or not.

Edit: Question re-attempt.

Using Win32 API I'm trying to find out how to get the start and end address of the executable pages of the process my code is executing in.

This is what I've tried:

```
        SYSTEM_INFO info;
    ZeroMemory( &info, sizeof( SYSTEM_INFO ) );
    GetNativeSystemInfo( &info ); // GetSystemInfo() might be wrong on WOW64.

    info.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo;
    ZeroMemory( &memInfo, sizeof( memInfo )  );
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)info.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    do
    {
        if ( VirtualQueryEx( thisProcess, (LPVOID)addr, &memInfo, sizeof( memInfo ) ) == 0 )
        {
            DWORD gle = GetLastError();
            if ( gle != ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER )
            {
                std::stringstream str;
                str << "VirtualQueryEx failed with: " << gle;
                MessageBoxA( NULL, str.str().c_str(), "Error", MB_OK );
            }
            break;
        }

        if ( memInfo.Type == MEM_IMAGE  )
        {
            // TODO: Scan this memory block for the the sigature
        }

        addr += info.dwPageSize;
    }
    while ( addr < (DWORD)info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress );
```

The reason for doing this is that I'm looking for an un-exported function by its signature as asked here:

[Find a function by it signature in Windows DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644717/find-a-function-by-it-signature-in-windows-dll)

See the answer about "code signature scanning".

While this is enumerating an address range I don't know if this is correct or not since I don't know what the expected range should be. Its just the best I could come up with from looking around MSDN.

Comment: your question is not well formulated.  Parts of it can be deduced (i.e. that you are talking about some kind of Windows), but you could definitely do better.  For instance, what exactly do you mean by a signature?

Comment: Please explain more clearly 1) Exactly what you're trying to do, 2) which platform you're working on, 3) what tools/procedures you're trying to use 4) an example of what's "not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the address range when signature scanning a module is from the start of the code section to the start + the section size. the start of the code section and its size are in the PE. most tools take the lazy route and scan the entire module (again using the PE to get the size, but with the module handle as the start address).

Comment: I think this is what I want, so I can read the PE header somehow using Win32 API's to get the code section start address and size?

What happens if for example the binary has been compressed with UPX or protected in some way? Is it still reliable to read the PE header? The code reading the PE header is executing in a DLL within the said binary.

Comment: @paulm: you can get the PE via `ImageNtHeader` (using the `HMODULE` as the base) from `windows.h`, and then spelunk the `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` entries to the required section, as for packed binaries, that depends if the PE is left intact or if its only the EP thats modified (you will need to code secotion to be decrypted before scanning ofc), this depends on the packer.

Comment: Annoyingly I've figure out that what I was after was in fact the "base address" and "image size".

I managed to get that info using:


  HINSTANCE instance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );

  MODULEINFO modInfo;
  ZeroMemory( &modInfo, sizeof( modInfo ) );
  GetModuleInformation( GetCurrentProcess(), instance, &modInfo, sizeof( modInfo ) );

I'll mark your answer as accepted, cheers!

Comment: That is very true, and very annoying given the file size of a lot of games these days. The .exe files are massive and the majority of it is not code.