# How can i lookup an address of the addresspace of a process?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

If i have an address from the address space of a process is there some way to lookup it's value?
I am debugging an application and can see that there is a comparison between a fixed number and the content of an address. I would be helpful if i knew this value of the address.
Best way would be to access it from Visual Studio.

Comment: Please can you be more precise with your terminology. There's no such thing as "an address of a process". Perhaps what you are looking for is `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: Visual studio didn't help?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771444/how-to-know-the-address-range-when-searching-for-a-function-by-its-signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the process is running, pause the execution (breakpoints etc...), go to `Debug -> Windows -> Memory -> Memory 1` and just paste the address. It will show the raw memory values in hexadecimal and ascii .

ps: There is `Memory 1` to `Memory 4` in VS2010. They aren't different from each other. It is just to facilitate monitoring several memory location at once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean:

[How to know the address range when searching for a function by its signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771444/how-to-know-the-address-range-when-searching-for-a-function-by-its-signature)

`GetModuleHandle()` will return the base address of the process, so that's your starting range.